# How to bind elements to each other?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have `Control` in which I bind my own class `Element` with "DataBindings". If I change "Width" and "Height", for example, in "E", Control change the same properties as well. But other side it don't work.

```
this.DataBindings.Add("Width", E, "Width");
this.DataBindings.Add("Height", E, "Height");
```

What is the best way to fix it? Only by hands, problem that there is many properties? Or exists something like "DataBindings"?

P.S. `Element` not inherited from any class, he haven't "DataBindings".
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it working both ways the following must be present:

- Both Proerties are required to be dependency properties or the containing class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- The `Mode` of the Binding must be `TwoWay`

EDIT: Just saw you are using WinForms - I'm not shure it works there the same way!

Comment: I think it's fair to say that no, it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class `E` for every property you want to bind.

Other way around won't work. `Control` has to have *Changed event for every property that needs to update datasource. For your example, you can try with `Size` property of the control, because there is a `SizeChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a control will report width and height property changes to the databinding listeners.

Try adding the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the control and take over the `Width` and `Height` properties yourself.

An example using a `Panel` control:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel, INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public new int Width {
    get { return base.Width; }
    set {
      base.Width = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Width");
    }
  }

  public new int Height {
    get { return base.Height; }
    set {
      base.Height = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Height");
    }
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Then change your databinding call to this, where `this` is your control with the above implementation:

```
this.DataBindings.Add("Width", E, "Width", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
this.DataBindings.Add("Height", E, "Height", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whan adding your bindings, use one of the overloads which allow you to to set the 
[`DataSourceUpdateMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) and set it to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`